# Eliminate [sound] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

At present there are two questions tagged [sound].

I cannot think of a question tagged [sound] that wouldn't be better served with a more descriptive [tag].

The two at present are [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/4908/2569) and [there](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/4785/2569).

- The first one would be better served with [DAW] [Fade] [Automation] [Sound-Forge] etc...
- The second question... maybe [Gain] [Volume] [Loudness] [Audacity] etc...

Comment: Most questions here have to do with sound. I can't see the tag helping anyone. +1

Comment: this makes total sense. This would muddy up searching by tag too

Answer (score 3):

I agree, I think [sound](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound) is far too vague to be useful. Furthermore, it's not something that would be generally thought of when asking an audio question (and, as we've seen, not many questions have it).

I'm up for getting rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree in principle but you have to also consider that this site is deals with both audio and video, and sound and audio are more or less synonymous. Are you proposing to prevent people tagging as 'audio' or 'video' also ... not that I'd object I think, but some people might think that it's strange not to be able to tag as audio or video.

Comment: No, I'm not proposing to eliminate the [audio] tag (though, I also might not object to that).  Although the site is about both A and V, I don't think each question should be tagged with an A or a V.  That certainly begs the question of the usefulness of an A tag and a V tag.  I would be interested to see a question that was ambiguous in that regard.  Also, check out [this](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/q/186/2569) meta post.  It touches on this subject.